# Unable to get windows messages from a process running under administrator process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, raw-input

I am listening to windows keyboard and mouse hooks by using RegisterRawInputDevices

```
 public static KeyboardMouseHook GetInstance()
  {
    if (_instance == null)
      {
        _instance = new KeyboardMouseHook();

      }
      return _instance;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This method is used to add the keyboard and mouse devices 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="windowHandle"></param>
   public void AddKeyboardMouseDevice(IntPtr windowHandle)
   {
     devices.Add(new RAWINPUTDEVICE(1, 6, 0x100, windowHandle));
     devices.Add(new RAWINPUTDEVICE(1, 2, 0x100, windowHandle));
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This method is used to register the mouse and keyboard events
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public bool RegisterDevices()
   {
     if (devices.Count == 0) return false;
     log.DebugFormat("Registering for keyboard and Mouse Events.");
     RAWINPUTDEVICE[] d = devices.ToArray();
     bool result = RegisterRawInputDevices(d, devices.Count, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)));
     return result;
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will get trigged when the premessage filter occurs and 
    /// it will process the message and raise an event according to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hRawInput"></param>
    /// <param name="wparam"></param>
    void ProcessRawInput(RawInput pData, IntPtr lparm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pData.Header.Type == RawInputType.Keyboard)
            {
                if ((pData.Data.Keyboard.Flags == 0) ||
                    (pData.Data.Keyboard.Flags == 2))
                {
                    int asciiCode = VKeyToChar(pData.Data.Keyboard.VirtualKey, pData.Data.Keyboard.MakeCode);
                    if (KeyHookEvent != null)
                    {
                        KeyHookEvent(this, new KeyHookEventArgs((Keys)asciiCode, IsAltPressed, IsCtrlPressed, IsShiftPressed));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (pData.Header.Type == RawInputType.Mouse)
            {
                POINT pt;
                GetCursorPos(out pt);
                if (MouseHookEvent != null)
                {
                    MouseHookEvent(this, new MouseHookEventArgs(pt.x, pt.y));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Exception occurred while processing the mouse event {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

my application will be running under user account. i am able to get all the mouse and keyboard events from the normal application. if the application runs under administrator privileges the i am not able to get the events.How can achieve this any suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: You might need to run your application with admin privileges as well

Comment: actually i need to run the application in user account only.

Comment: If you run the application in user account only, then you can't access process which are running in admin mode.

Comment: Then you can't access data of an admin process. There's are reason that there exists a distinction between user and admin processes and it would be terrible if a user process could access an admin process/data.